# Flutter Refreshindicator rebuilding Listview.Builder after adding new items with StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

I have a RefreshIndicator contained within a StreamBuilder. Anytime the Streambuilder has new data added, the RefreshIndicator rebuilds its Listview.Builder jumping to the top in the process.

StreamBuilder(
stream: apiResultStream.stream,
builder:
(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
if(snapshot.hasError){
print("has error");
}
if(!snapshot.hasData)
{

```
            return  RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: () {
                  _apiResult=[];
                  return _loadMoreData(0);
                },
                child:snapshot.data.length == 0 ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(child: Text('No items', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                ):SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child:ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder:(BuildContext ctxt, int index){
                      return InkWell(
                          
                          child:TripItem(key: ValueKey(snapshot.data[index].Id),item:snapshot.data[index])
                      );
                    }
                    ,itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    key: UniqueKey(),


                ))

            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to add a GlobalKey to the RefreshIndicator. This prevents the RefreshIndicator from rebuilding its child when the StreamBuilder has new data.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: apiResultStream.stream,
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print("has error");
          }
          if(!snapshot.hasData)
          {


       
            return  RefreshIndicator(
                key: _refreshIndicatorKey ,
                onRefresh: () {
                  _apiResult=[];
                  return _loadMoreData(0);
                },
                child:snapshot.data.length == 0 ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(child: Text('No items', style: 
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: 
                  FontWeight.bold),)),
                ):SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child:ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder:(BuildContext ctxt, int index){
                      return InkWell(
                          
                          child:TripItem(key: 
            ValueKey(snapshot.data[index].Id),item:snapshot.data[index])
                      );
                    }
                    ,itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    key: UniqueKey(),


                ))

);
```